# Seeking works by tanaim or amoraim

Tags: jewish-books, tannaim, amoroim

To the best of my knowledge there is only 1 full work that was authored by a rabbi from the period of the tanaim or amoraim is the work seder olam by r' yose ben chalafta. I would like to know if there are any other books that have a single author from this same period

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this qualifies as a book per say; Megillat Taanit which was written by Channiah ben Chezkia (Shabbat 13b)

Answer (score 4):

[Sifra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sifra)

Sifra (Aramaic: סִפְרָא) is the Halakhic midrash to Leviticus. It is frequently quoted in the Talmud, and the study of it followed that of the Mishnah. Like Leviticus itself, the midrash is occasionally called "Torat Kohanim"...

According to the Wiki article, Maimonides and others have declared that the title "Sifra debe Rab" indicates Rav as the author of the Sifra.

The Malbim, posits that R. Ḥiyya was the redactor of the Sifra. There are no less than 39 passages in Yerushalmi and the midrashim in which expositions found also in the Sifra are quoted in the name of R. Ḥiyya, and the fact that no tannaim subsequent to Rebbi are mentioned in the Sifra supports the view that the book was composed during the time of that scholar.

Answer (score 3):

While it’s unclear who wrote [Avos d’Rebbi Nassan](https://www.sefaria.org/Avot_D'Rabbi_Natan?lang=bi), many Rishonim, including Rashbatz and Machzor Vitri, write that it was indeed written by the Tanna R’ Nassan.

Technically the entirety of Mishnayos qualifies: they were composed by Rebbi Yehudah HaNasi, based on the works of many Tannaim (though primarily R’ Meir and R’ Akiva).

Answer (score 2):

[Pirke De-Rabbi Eliezer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirke_De-Rabbi_Eliezer)

Pirke de-Rabbi Eliezer (Pirke De Rabbi Eliezer, Aramaic: פרקי דרבי אליעזר, or פרקים דרבי אליעזר, Chapters of Rabbi Eliezar) is an aggadic-midrashic work on the Torah containing exegesis and retellings of biblical stories. The composition enjoyed widespread circulation and recognition throughout Jewish history, and continues to do so in the present. Traditionally, Pirke De Rabbi Eliezer has been understood to be a tannaitic composition which originated with the tanna Rabbi Eliezer ben Hyrcanus, - a disciple of Rabbi Yochanan ben Zakai and teacher of Rabbi Akiva - and his disciples.